# Css image-orientation seems to ignore none and use EXIF data when displaying image in my test code

Tags: css, image, browser, orientation, exif

I'm working with overriding image-orientation from different devices. In my test code the setting of 'none' never seems to take effect. The images always display as if the EXIF orientation data from the image is being factored in.

Stepping back to try and find something that does work, I located an example (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation) from the MDN docs that demonstrates this functionality working. The code appears below. When I go to the MDN page and use the radio button to toggle between 'from-image' and 'none' it works as expected. (The bird image appears upside down when none is selected.)

I copied the code from the sample page above into a page on my local machine and it doesn't seem to work for me. Regardless of whether I select 'none' or 'from-image' the image always displays the same. (I'm using the same browser.) In my test code, I do link to the same image as the MDN example, to ensure that saving a local copy doesn't effect it in any way. I've also confirmed when the radio button is toggled the image-orientation setting does get overridden in the DOM element but the image display does not change. Here is a codepen (https://codepen.io/kwright402/pen/RwQxGKG) that demonstrates the issue. (It contains the same code as posted below.)

I've tested on Chrome (101), Opera (86) and Edge (101) all on Windows as well as Safari (15.5) on Mac and I get the same results across all the browsers.

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    svg:not(:root) {
      display: block;
    }

   .playable-code {
      background-color: #f4f7f8;
      border: none;
      border-left: 6px solid #558abb;
      border-width: medium medium medium 6px;
      color: #4d4e53;
      height: 100px;
      width: 90%;
      padding: 10px 10px 0;
   }

  .playable-canvas {
      border: 1px solid #4d4e53;
      border-radius: 2px;
  }

  .playable-buttons {
      text-align: right;
      width: 90%;
      padding: 5px 10px 5px 26px;
  }
  </style>

  <style>
  #image {
    image-orientation: from-image;
    /* Can be changed in the live sample */
  }

  img {
    margin: .5rem 0;
  }

  label {
    font-family: monospace;
  }
  </style>

  <title>image-orientation - orienting_image_from_image_data - code sample</title>
</head>

<body>

  <img id="image" src="https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation/oriole.jpg" alt="Orientation taken from the image" style="image-orientation: none;">

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="from-image" name="orientation" value="from-image" checked="">
    <label for="from-image">from-image</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="none" name="orientation" value="none">
    <label for="none">none</label>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('change', evt => {
       document.getElementById("image").style.imageOrientation = evt.target.value;
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head on this same issue for a while, I figure out it was a CORS issue.  It failed when I tested locally.  It only worked when I applied image-orientation tag to image on same domain.  It's not a solution, but it at least explains the issue.

This discussion helped me figure out issue:
[Link](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5165)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).